# How to cluster markers in google map using kotlin and google maps utils

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I am currently facing this problem[That you can see in the picture bellow)

[image: Too many markers picture]

How can I cluster all my markers, to show only 5 our 6 BIG markerks at beginning to indicate where are markers and if I zoom he increases the number of markers and the size of the markers decreases.

This is my code

This is my MapFragment

```
class MapFragment: BaseFragment<FragmentMapBinding, MapViewModel>(),OnMapReadyCallback , GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener{


    private var stationList = mutableListOf<Station>()

    override fun onCameraMove() {

    }

    lateinit var mGoogleMaps:GoogleMap

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(context )
        mGoogleMaps = googleMap
        googleMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
    }



    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MapFragment()
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory


    override fun layoutToInflate() = R.layout.fragment_map

    override fun defineViewModel() = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MapViewModel::class.java)

    override fun doOnCreated() {
        mapView.onCreate(null)
        mapView.onResume()
        mapView.getMapAsync(this)


        viewModel.getStations(activity?.supportFragmentManager!!, R.id.fragment_container, context!!)
        viewModel.retrieveStations().observe(this, Observer<List<Station>> {
            addItems(it)
            for (i in 0 until stationList.size) {
                val name = LatLng(stationList[i].latitude, stationList[i].longitude)
                mGoogleMaps.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                        .position(name)
                        //.title(name)
                        //.snippet(name.toString() + " is cool")
                        // .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        //       .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_pin )))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)))

            }
        })
    }

    fun addItems(items: List<Station>){
        stationList.addAll(items)
    }
```

The other classes the correspond to this are API requests, so for the purpose of short the code, I receive all long and lat from each station from the API. I have seen the cluster google maps utils but I cant put that to work. Can someone help?

This is my model

```
data class Station(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        val latitude: Double,
        val longitude: Double,
        val address: String,
        val post_code: String,
        val location: String,
        val serviceStore: Int,
        val serviceMechanicalWorkshop: Int,
        val serviceRestaurant: Int,
        val serviceWash: Int
)
```

Comment: Do you try to accomplish that using [official guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering). What problem exactly do you have?

Comment: @ConstOrVar, I resolve the issue above can you see this other question I have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354283/my-getmarker-is-always-null-when-i-click-on-cluster-marker   , the problem is that my Rederer.getMarker() is always null, can you please help me? :S